# how can i stop the thief from using my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, security, contacts, graphics

My i phone 5 was stolen and i'm freaking out because the thieves keep on using my i phone. i knew this because when i contacted my i phone it answered me.

i tried to locate it but it keep on showing offline then i remotely erase my phone but it seems that the thief is not connecting to the internet. i'm afraid because he has the freedom to access my contacts and pictures! please help me.

Comment: If you contact your provider and ask them to give you a new sim. This should stop the the sim working in the phone. This may mean the phone will need to connect to the internet to activate a new one. I put this as a comment because I am unsure if this would work

Answer (score 1):

I believe in some country you can file a complain with your IMEI number and UDID (which you can have on your purchase proof or in iTunes in last device) and the police can then ask Apple to block the phone.

Anyway, the best practice here is to file the complain, you never know what happen with your data...

BTW, no need for internet connection because it's directly over GSM network

Comment: Unfortunately any IMEI can be [spoofed](http://www.ehow.com/how_7362296_change-imei-code-iphone.html)  with ease.

Comment: Sure, UDID too but only on jailbroken phone which is not really something easy to sell unless the buyer doesn't want to know where the phone comes from. Someone that wants to steal your phone can steal it and never be found but doing this will make things a bit less simple for the thief. You really don't want to give up your phone just because it is possible for someone to steal it the proper way... I would make it as painful as possible imo.

Comment: @TechHunter From this perspective... ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to wait until he makes contact with the internet.
When he contacts the internet, it will automatic download your requests to lock or erase your device.